# Incorrect syntax near '00' when entering Date via SOAP request using PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, soap

I'm making a SOAP request in PHP and one of the fields 'START YEAR' is in Date format.

If I write it as such:

```
$date=date_create("2019-06-01 00:00:00");
$startyear=date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

The error I get is `Incorrect syntax near '00'`

However if I try:

```
$date=date_create("2019-06-01");
$startyear=date_format($date,"Y-m-d");
```

The request is successful, but the date is entered is
"1905-07-06T00:00:00"

I understand that the second attempt would give an incorrect date, but I don't see what the issue is with the first.

Comment: *"I understand that the second attempt would give an incorrect date"* Why?? it generates `2019-06-01` which is perfect valid PHP date format and a SQL date format unless you are trying to insert it on a `DATETIME`  datetype in SQL

Comment: Does it work if you change it to `date_format($date,DateTime::W3C);`?

Comment: What does SQL have to do with it? You only shown a error which look like to be SQL Server (MSSQL) related.  Can you atleast show the generated SQL code? And table structure? And provide a beter user case with expected results.